# Quickbooks API v3 release

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We are trying to use QB API for java (ipp-java-devkit 2.0.9) but we are not able to fetch refunds....there is no support to know whether an invoice is a refund or not.

I've read in some posts that v3 will have such support but it is not available yet. Do you know whether QB intends to release this version or will they stop their development? (I read months ago v3 release was planned for 2012 but we are in 2013 and it has not been released yet).

v2 is very incomplete, its documentation (javadoc) is really really bad (it contains many errors on fields availability for QBD or QBO) so v3 is our last hope for an usable product that matches our needs as well.

Regards

Comment: My guess, based on what I've seen so far, is that it's vaporware. Intuit has pulled the roadmap from their website, doesn't respond to questions about it, stopped updating the spec for v3, and in response to support tickets just says "we're not ready to release this yet".

Comment: There is an Intuit Data Services v3 Roadmap and we will be sharing the roadmap with developers soon for feedback. The previous roadmap was outdated which is why it was removed.

Comment: A roadmap isn't much good if you constantly let it get outdated, don't communicate with your developer community at all for 6+ months about the status of things, then pull it from your website completely... just saying... v3 was supposed to be available in beta 4+ months ago, and no one has given developers even a hint at what's going on.

Comment: And the roadmap is just not enough is the devkit is not stable. In current v2 API you have to test each getter in order to know whether it's availbable or not...you can't rely on documentation as it is junk. Some methods say: not available for QBO but it is...others says available for QBO but it isn't. 
We even tried to download code from the repository for v3 but it changed a lot and almost every single line stopped working...and once we modified our code...it didn't work either...so I assume there is still to much work left to get a stable product from v3

Answer (score 0):

QB desktop allows small business owners to enter a negative quantity to return merchandise (inventory will be adjusted accordingly). So as long as the total of the invoice is positive, users can have as many lines with negative quantity to mimic merchandise that has been returned (aka refunded)

Comment: We are using QBO which has less features than QBD and we have been using credit notes since we started using QBO...so this would not be a valid approach for our case.
Besides that, API for QBO supports less features than API for QBD so maybe what we need is available in the API for QBD but not for QBO